# Spacing not working in description environment

Tags: description

I have done this before but for some reason it's not working in my current file.

```
\begin{description}[largest]
 \item[small] Foo
 \item[largest] Foobar
\end{description}
```

This above code give the error

```
package enumitem error: largest undefined
```

Comment: an `r` is missing in `\end{description}`. Plus you have to post MWE, mimimal working examples.

Comment: @Denis the "r" is not the issue.

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You perhaps want

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[widest=largest,itemindent=*,align=left]
 \item[small] Foo
 \item[largest] Foobar
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Fixed. I had imported the `enumitem` package. It works fine without that.

Comment: without the enumitem package `description` does not have an optional argument so `[largest]` would be an error. This does not seem to answer the question asked.